# polars DataFrame - search strings from list

Tags: python-polars

I need to search in string that contains a substring.
I am looking for the efficient way to do so.

Slow version:

```
import polars as pl

def search_text(queries, text):
    return [query for query in queries if query in text]


pl_df = pl.DataFrame( {
        "Title": ["I am aa", "I am bbob"]
    })

queries = ['aa', 'bb']

pl_df = pl_df.with_column(pl.col('Title').apply(lambda text: search_text(queries, text)).alias('Title_match'))
print(pl_df)


shape: (2, 2)
┌───────────┬─────────────┐
│ Title     ┆ Title_match │
│ ---       ┆ ---         │
│ str       ┆ list[str]   │
╞═══════════╪═════════════╡
│ I am aa   ┆ ["aa"]      │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ I am bbob ┆ ["bb"]      │
└───────────┴─────────────┘
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try `.extract_all()`

You can combine your query strings into a single regex:

```
>>> import re
... 
... queries = "aa", "bb", "am"
... query =  "|".join(map(re.escape, sorted(queries, key=len, reverse=True)))
... 
... pl_df.with_column(
...    pl.col("Title").str.extract_all(query)
...      .alias("Title_match")
... )   
shape: (2, 2)
┌───────────┬──────────────┐
│ Title     | Title_match  │
│ ---       | ---          │
│ str       | list[str]    │
╞═══════════╪══════════════╡
│ I am aa   | ["am", "aa"] │
├───────────┼──────────────┤
│ I am bbob | ["am", "bb"] │
└─//────────┴─//───────────┘
```