# polars DataFrame - search strings from list - list of strings containing white spaces

Tags: python, string, dataframe, list, python-polars

Stemming from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74534117/polars-dataframe-search-strings-from-list/74535268#74535268?newreg=429cfbe984f44868aff68bc074f0362f) question with a great answer.

Lets suppose I have white spaces in my list of strings:

```
     queries = "sports jackets", "n95", "face mask"
```

When executing the line:
`query =  "|".join(map(re.escape, sorted(queries, key=len, reverse=True)))`

I receive an escape error due to the white spaces.

I tired to solve this error by adding regex whitespaces in the list of strings like:

`queries = r"sports[\s]jackets", r"spray[\s]paint", r"face[\s]mask"`

This stopped the error from occurring but does not match the strings correctly, how do i avoid this error while still Obtaining the desired output of :

| Title | Title_match |
| --- | --- |
| Green sports jackets | ["sports jacket"] |
| N95 face mask | ["n95", "face mask"] |

Comment: Can we you please [edit] your question and make it a [mcve]? What error do you get when you run which code? The `"|".join(map(re.escape, sorted(queries, key=len, reverse=True)))` does not give me an error. Why do you use `re.escape` on strings that are not regular expressions? Did you already see [ask]?

Comment: Please provide the error you're getting after running just the lines beginning `queries=` and `query=` as I run those two lines with no error. I see no reason why spaces would induce an error there.